# automatic replacement of text in wpf richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, richtextbox

I have a WPF .NET 4 C# `RichTextBox` and I'm wanting to replace certain characters within that text box with other characters, this is to happen on the `KeyUp` event.

What I'm trying to achieve is replace acronyms with full words, e.g.:

pc = personal computer 

sc = starcraft

 etc...

I've looked a few similar threads, but anything I've found hasn't been successful in my scenario.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to do this with a list of acronyms. However, I'm having issues with even replacing a single acronym, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` does not have a property for `Text` to detect its value, you may detect its value using the following

```
string _Text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

Then, you may change `_Text` and post the new string using the following

```
_Text = _Text.Replace("pc", "Personal Computer");
if (_Text != new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text)
{
new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text;
}
```

So, it'd look like this

```
string _Text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
_Text = _Text.Replace("pc", "Personal Computer"); // Replace pc with Personal Computer
if (_Text != new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text)
{
new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text; // Change the current text to _Text
}
```

**Remark**: Instead of using `Text.Replace("pc", "Personal Computer");` you may declare a `List<String>` in which you save the characters and its replacements

**Example:**

```
    List<string> _List = new List<string>();
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        string _Text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
        for (int count = 0; count < _List.Count; count++)
        {
            string[] _Split = _List[count].Split(','); //Separate each string in _List[count] based on its index
            _Text = _Text.Replace(_Split[0], _Split[1]); //Replace the first index with the second index
        }
        if (_Text != new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text)
        {
        new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text;
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The comma will be used to separate multiple items
        _List.Add("pc,Personal Computer");
        _List.Add("sc,Star Craft");

    }
```

Thanks,

 I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @Mike No problems at all, Glad I could help :)

Comment: I find this line `new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text` really strange. Is this really changes the RichTextBox text?