# How can I replace ' ' with "་"ཚེགfor WPF Richtextbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am trying to replace ' ' with a Tibetian character "་"ཚེག in a WPF Rich Text box in VS 2010.

Lets say I have a rich text box with text as follows:

```
སྐད བརྡའི སྒྲིག རིམ སྐྲུན པའི་
```

Following is what I expected to get as output by using WPF richTextBox.

```
སྐད་བརྡའི་སྒྲིག་རིམ་སྐྲུན་པའི་
```

I have a Language keyboard:

Monlam Bod-yig3.01 Unicode TCRCKB-

Comment: What do you mean by 'gap' here? Please write your question in english.

Comment: thanks for ur respose, gap means for space like  (སྐད བརྡའི སྒྲིག རིམ སྐྲུན པའི་) the space between the words, by the way sorry for the wrong interpretation :)

Comment: Please tell me if I am correct. You have a rich text box filled with some text. In that text, you want to replace all ' '(space) with "་"ཚེག

Comment: yeah, thats what i expected to do and i wanna  to use it in WPF RichtextBox  of 2010(C#). thanks for your great response :)

Comment: Your original sample contains five spaces and is 18 characters long. You want to replace ` ` with `"་"ཚེག`, which is five characters long. I would therefore expect the final string to contain `18 + (5 - 1) * 5` characters (38 characters), but your expected result contains 186 characters. How does this work?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Exactly my question. And there are spaces too in the final string. How are they generated?

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah my original sample contains five spaces and is 18 characters long, therefore i want to use "་"ཚེག instead of using"space" in (སྐད བརྡའི སྒྲིག རིམ སྐྲུན པའི་) thats what i expected to do like this - སྐད་བརྡའི་སྒྲིག་རིམ་སྐྲུན་པའི་ - by using WPF richtextbox

Comment: hey Nilay Vishwakarma, I have used your given code, the replacement is coming properly but cursor is jumping to the starting point of the every lines. how can i over come that ?? Thanks

Comment: @verena, refer the edit. It might be useful

Comment: @Nilay, thanks for  your great help and i have done the replacement part, but can you please tell me any ways where i can check the spellings for the above language rather than the custom dictionary and also "line break" which means i want to break the next line from"་"ཚེག onward as we are using "space bar" for English. i am using WindowsFormApp in vb.net. Thanks

Comment: @verena You need a spell checker for Tibetan Script?

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma yeah thats what i want to do now and i already done custom dictionary for spelling check but thats not that much useful, so thought to do new spell checker in WindowFormApp and i also  got one problem on "Line break" means every next line will going to break after "་"ཚེག, but sadly its not happening :(

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.columbia.edu/~ph2046/RnD/Hackett/TibComp.htm), [this](https://github.com/eroux/tibetan-spellchecker) and [this](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/tibetan-spellchecker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this link for your reference : [automatic replacement of text in wpf richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13041548/3331861)

---

By [Picrofo Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712248/picrofo-software)

Because `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` does not have a property for `Text` to detect its value, you may detect its value using the following

```
string _Text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

Then, you may change `_Text` and post the new string using the following

```
_Text = _Text.Replace("pc", "Personal Computer");
if (_Text != new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text)
{
new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text;
}
```

So, it'd look like this

```
string _Text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
_Text = _Text.Replace("pc", "Personal Computer"); // Replace pc with Personal Computer
if (_Text != new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text)
{
new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text; // Change the current text to _Text
}
```

**Remark**: Instead of using `Text.Replace("pc", "Personal Computer");` you may declare a `List<String>` in which you save the characters and its replacements

**Example:**

```
    List<string> _List = new List<string>();
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        string _Text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
        for (int count = 0; count < _List.Count; count++)
        {
            string[] _Split = _List[count].Split(','); //Separate each string in _List[count] based on its index
            _Text = _Text.Replace(_Split[0], _Split[1]); //Replace the first index with the second index
        }
        if (_Text != new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text)
        {
        new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text;
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The comma will be used to separate multiple items
        _List.Add("pc,Personal Computer");
        _List.Add("sc,Star Craft");

    }
```

---

The user here is trying to replace pc with Personal Computer,
You can emulate the same behavior by replacing ' ' with "་"ཚེག.

If this is not satisfactory for your needs you may try the following step:

1. Raise a TextChangedEvent for the RichTextBox
2. Check if the text is ' ', from the eventargs
3. If true, remove a character from RichTextBox.Text and add "་"ཚེག

**EDIT: Please see the select statement (Although it is a crude method, and would be useful only when you type after selection)**

```
string _Text = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
_Text = _Text.Replace(" ", "“་”ཚེག"); // Replace pc with Personal Computer
if (_Text != new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text)
{
new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text+" "; // Change the current text to _Text
}
richTextBox1.Selection.Select(_Text.Length-1, _Text.Length);
```

Comment: @verena: Please use the comment function to ask the author something. Don't try to edit the post.